# How to set progressive image in iOS using SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I tried to load an image progressively in my app. Basically what I tried is while the image is loading, I want to show the fully loaded image from blurred state. I tried,

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://profile.microsoft.com/RegsysProfileCenter/Images/personal_info.jpg"]
                      options:0
                     progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                         [self.profileBtn setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:&receivedSize length:sizeof(receivedSize)] scale:15] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     }
                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                        if (image) {
                            // [self.profileBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        }
                    }];
```

Is it possible to load an image progressively using SDWebImage. Please help me with this.

Comment: Do you have any thumb URL which can be downloaded quickly. in that case you can show the thumb image until the large image is not downloaded. I had the same condition once which i solve with the thumb image url. Otherwise use of progress bar is only option.

Comment: see this once it helps you https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage/blob/master/UIImageView%2BUIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.m

Comment: You can following this link to get your answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267576/how-to-show-blurred-image-before-downloadinglike-in-whatsapp-in-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35267576/how-to-show-blurred-image-before-downloadinglike-in-whatsapp-in-ios)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this implementation

```
+ (void)loadImageWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString forImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[Utilities stringToURL:urlString]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage placeHolderImage]
                          options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload];
}
```

The option says that

```
/**
     * This flag enables progressive download, the image is displayed progressively during download as a browser would do.
     * By default, the image is only displayed once completely downloaded.
     */
    SDWebImageProgressiveDownload = 1 << 3,
```

Comment: Note that this requires that the files are saved using Progressive JPEG compression.

Comment: If you want to display the image from the blurred state, I think one possible solution is creating a blur layer on top of your placeholder image with the blur value set by the percentage of download completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can show percentage of downloading on temp label or below activity indicator (can show activityindicator on image view or button till download is not completed) like in  progress block,

```
 NSInteger downloadCompleted = (receivedSize/ expectedSize) * 100;
 label.text = downloadCompleted; //temp label on image view or below activityindicator
```

Hope this will help :)